# Como puedo generar mi consulta para no seleccionar registros nulos?

Tags: sql-server-2017

Tengo el siguiente sp que devuelve calculos y algunos registros. Me gustaria que el resultado de la consulta pueda ignorar los registros nulos.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ReportEmployee]
@ClockIn AS datetime2,
@ClockOut AS datetime2
AS
SELECT DISTINCT UserName AS 'Technician', 
CustomerName AS Customer,
SUM((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ClockIn, ClockOut)/60.0)) AS TotalHours,
SUM((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ClockIn, ClockOut)/60.0)) * WorkOrderHourlyRate AS Total
FROM Customer c
JOIN WorkOrder w
ON c.Id = w.Customer_Id
JOIN AspNetUsers u
ON w.User_Id = u.Id
WHERE clockin BETWEEN @ClockIn AND @ClockOut
GROUP BY 
c.CustomerName, u.UserName, u.WorkOrderHourlyRate;`introducir el código aquí`
```

Si me pudieran apoyar con alguna solución se los agradecería un montón.

### El resultado de la consulta es el sig:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo validaría en el where que `clockIn` y `clockOut` no sean nulos

Comment: solo añade IS NOT NULL como condición de cada variable que desees en el where

Comment: ya lo intenté pero me marca error de sintaxis, o quizas no lo estoy haciendo bien. Espesificamente donde de ve ir ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se ha solucionado la consulta incluyendo

```
HAVING SUM((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ClockIn, ClockOut)/60.0)) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: No olvides tanto explicar el funcionamiento del código como [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta. Por lo primero, _esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._